# how insert image of a ul list in a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to insert an image inside of a div (.slider), when I click in a link "prev" and "next", I have a structure like this:

```
<a class="prev"></a>
    <div class="slider">
    </div>
<a class="next"></a>

    <div class="thumbnails">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
        <li><img src="" alt="" /></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Both side of div.slider, I have two links "prev" and "next", to go to next and prev images, how can I do it with jQuery, or, javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried anything???

Comment: yes, but, without sucess, not work, spend all my day trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.prev').click(function(){
   if(current>0){
       current--;
       changeImage(current);
   }
});

$('.next').click(function(){
    current++;
    changeImage(current);
});

var current=0;
changeImage(current);
function changeImage(index){
  if($('li img').eq(index).length){
      var src=$('li img').eq(index).attr('src');
      $('.slider').html('<img src="'+src+'" />');
  }
}
```

try something like this

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to add an img element than working with html:

```
var current = 0;
$("a.prev").click(function(){
  $(".slider img").attr("src", $(".thumbnails li").eq(current--).attr("src") );
})
$("a.next").click(function(){
  $(".slider img").attr("src", $(".thumbnails li").eq(current++).attr("src") );
})
```

Also, make sure you handle cases where prev causes current < 0 or when current >= $(".thumbnails li").length